# Hibernate: I get a "no persistent classes found for query class"

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I keep getting a `no persistent classes found for query class` when I attempt to do a query and I am not sure why that is? I was able to establish a connection successfully but I do not know what is causing the no persistent class issue?

The size of the list of CarProducts returns 0

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


/**
 * TODO: Enter Javadoc
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "car_product")
public class CarProduct {

    //~ Instance fields ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carid;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productid;

    @Column(name = "attribute")
    private String attribute;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    //~ Constructors ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates a new CarProduct object.
     */
    public CarProduct() {
    }     

    //~ Methods --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public String getCarid() {
        return carid;
    }

    public void setCarid(String carid) {
        this.carid = carid;
    }

    public String getProductid() {
        return productid;
    }

    public void setProductid(String productid) {
        this.productid = productid;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);               
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        // I have to specify the package name too and it is really annoying but it throws an error if just do "from CarProduct".    
        List<CarProduct> carProducts = session.createQuery("from com.searchresults.CarProduct").list();
        System.out.println("THE SIZE OF THE LIST IS: " + carProducts.size());

        session.getTransaction().commit();


}
```

---

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">None of your business</property>
        <property name="connection.username">None of your business</property>
        <property name="connection.password">None of your business</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!--Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <!-- Print our the SQL to console -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

I get the following StrackTrace:

`HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1
HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [None of your business]
HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=none of your business, password=none of your business}
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from com.searchresults.CarProduct
THE SIZE OF THE LIST IS: 0`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell Hibernate where to find the Entity classes. One way is to explicitly mention it under `session-factory`. Please make sure you have the fully qualified class name in there. Your example contains a default package, so thats what I put in here.

```
<mapping class="CarProduct"/>
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it but now I am unable to do a query for a column. I put `"from com.searchresults.CarProduct where carid='blah'"` but I get an error under `carid`.

Comment: Is this query right? `("from com.searchresults.CarProduct")`?

Comment: @Robben You need to post the error to help us understand the problem

Comment: @Julian Yeah, it's valid HQL syntax.

Comment: @Julian yea, it's you're right, it's very strange but it doesn't work if I don't specify the package name. @Pradeep , it doesn't give an error but it just highlights red under the `carid`.

Comment: Use `"from com.searchresults.CarProduct carp where carp.carid='blah'"`

Comment: @Robben I am assuming you are using a parameterized query, like `"from com.searchresults.CarProduct carp where carp.carid=:carid"`. See here https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the annotated class into the hibernate-cfg.xml file
inside the session-factory
`<mapping class="com.searchresults.CarProduct"/>`